# how to mongoimport import by parts (big file)

Tags: csv, mongodb, import

How to import big file using mongoimport by parts

if I import the file all at once, in the middle of 50% of completion, mongodb will crash because the server will run out of memory (2GB of RAM)

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot import more than 2gb of data to 32-bit server (it does not depend on the file size). Upgrade to 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import a jsonArray file which is more than 16MB in size (it does not depend on the architechture!)

Source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/